# JMS Connection to Red Hat AMQ 7 running on Openshift using a secured route

Tags: ssl, jms, openshift, activemq-artemis, amq

We're running AMQ 7 on Openshift 3.11. When trying to connect java clients using JMS from the Openshift platform there is no issue. However, to access it from an external client I've created a secure route to the 61617 port. On Openshift this route should be available as https://my-route:443 and I can ping my-route. But how can I use this to establish a JMS connection, I keep on getting:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:886)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at be.digipolis.artemis_consumer.ArtemisConsumerApplication.run(ArtemisConsumerApplication.java:39)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at be.digipolis.artemis_consumer.ArtemisConsumerApplication.main(ArtemisConsumerApplication.java:25)
Caused by: ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:821)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:884)
    ... 8 more
```

My code:

```java
Connection connection = null;
InitialContext initialContext = null;

try {
    initialContext = new InitialContext();
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/hugo");
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
    connection = cf.createConnection(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("This is a text message");
    logger.info("Sent message: ", message.getText());
    producer.send(message);
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
    connection.start();
    TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(5000);
    logger.info("Received message : ", messageReceived);
    initialContext.close();
} catch (NamingException | JMSException e) {
    logger.error("Exception", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (initialContext != null) {
        initialContext.close();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

And jndi.properties :

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
connectionFactory.ConnectionFactory=tcp://my-route:443
queue.queue/hugo=hugo
```

I had to already use `tcp` instead of `https`, otherwise I get "invalid broker url".

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tcp://my-route:443?httpEnabled=true&sslEnabled=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ... It changes the error to : Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]